# Using dask with pd.read_fwf()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dask, dask-distributed

I want to use dask instead of pandas in order to speed up my file reading.

I have the code below that shows my problem, the code runs indefinitely without completing the task :

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
with open("tmp_gdo.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(["A"*300 for _ in range(10_000_000)])


dd.read_fwf(
    "tmp_gdo.txt",
    colspecs=[(i*10, i*10+10) for i in range(30)],
    blocksize=640,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to change blocksize

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
with open("tmp_gdo.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(["A"*300 for _ in range(10_000_000)])


dd.read_fwf(
    "tmp_gdo.txt",
    colspecs=[(i*10, i*10+10) for i in range(30)],
    blocksize=6400,
)
```